# Double dual module

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, modules, dual-spaces

Let $A$ be an associative algebra (or a ring) and $M$ a free finite-dimensional left $A$-module. Then there exists a right $A$-module structure with $M^\perp$ (the dual space of $M$) as the underlying space, equipped with the action defined by
\begin{equation}
(\varphi a)(m) := \varphi(a m)
\end{equation}

for all $\varphi \in M^{\perp}$, $a \in A$ and $m \in M$. Since $(M^{\perp})^\perp \cong M$, I'm wondering if the original action $a \cdot m$ on $M$ can be re-obtained via the definition of the action on the dual space twice. I've attempted this myself by substituting $\varphi^{\perp} \in M$ for $\varphi$ and $m^{\perp} \in M^{\perp}$ for $m$ in the centred equation above, however this obtains $\varphi^{\perp}(a m^{\perp}) = a\varphi^{\perp}( m^{\perp}) = a \delta_{\varphi, m}$, which equals $a$ if and only if $\varphi = m$ and zero otherwise (assuming the bases of $M$ and $M^{\perp}$ are chosen appropriately); so perhaps I'm missing something.

I've tagged category theory, as this comes up in the dual equivalence of categories $\text{mod}(A)$ and $\text{mod}(A^{\text{op}})$ under the standard duality functor $D$.

Comment: The canonical map from M to its double dual that you learned about in linear algebra is indeed an isomorphism of left A-modules. The A linearity of the map you can check directly by calculation, and you know it is bijective from linear algebra.

Comment: What do you mean by $\varphi^\perp$ and $m^\perp$?

Comment: @EricWofsey To differentiate from $\varphi$ being an element of $M^{\perp}$ and $m$ being an element of $M$.

Comment: But then how are you getting $\varphi^\perp(m^\perp)=\delta_{\varphi,m}$?  What are $\varphi$ and $m$ here?

Comment: I should have mentioned that $m$ is a basis element of $M$ and $\varphi$ is a basis element of $M^{\perp}$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your basis exactly.  In any case, this is easier to understand without using a basis, actually.

Comment: Wait, is $A$ supposed to be an algebra over some field $k$ and all of these duals are duals over $k$, rather than over $A$?  If that's the case then $\varphi^\perp(am^\perp)$ does not need to equal $a\varphi^\perp(m^\perp)$ since the elements of the dual are only $k$-linear, not $A$-linear.

Comment: Is the action of $A$ on $M^\perp$ defined correctly? I'd have thought that to give $M^\perp$ right $A$-module structure, you needed instead $(\phi a)(m) := \phi(a)m$. Then it follows that $(\phi a)b= \phi(ab)$, but that doesn't seem to follow on your definition. On your definition, I think you get $\phi(ab)=(\phi b)a$.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical bijection $F:M\to (M^\perp)^\perp$ is defined by $F(m)(\varphi)=\varphi(m)$ for $m\in M$ and $\varphi\in M^\perp$ (so, $F(m)$ is the homomorphism $M^\perp\to A$ that sends $\varphi$ to $\varphi(m)$).  So now, your question is just whether $F$ is $A$-linear.  Plugging in the definitions, $$F(am)(\varphi)=\varphi(am)=(\varphi a)(m)=F(m)(\varphi a)=(aF(m))(\varphi),$$ where at the end $aF(m)$ is defined using the $A$-module structure of the double dual $(M^\perp)^\perp$.  Thus $F(am)=aF(m)$, so $F$ is indeed $A$-linear.